# How to remove the window error message from the "allowBlank: false" config of the rowediting plugin

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs5

How to remove the window error message (displayed on the right side) from the "allowBlank: false" config of the rowediting plugin when new row is added?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1s26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the showTooltip method in the RowEditor class:

```
Ext.define('RowEditorOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.RowEditor',

    showToolTip: function() {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, although I didn't know about the errorSummary config. Bretch's answer is obviously the better one

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to override the `Ext.grid.RowEdit`. Just add `errorSummary: false` in the plugin.

```js
plugins: [{
  ptype: 'rowediting',
  clicksToEdit: 2,
  errorSummary: false
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Bretch. Had seen in the previous study the config errorSummary, but had not realized the context in which it was used. I will use your solution because is the better one (also Zeke agrees)

Answer (score 0):

add errorSummary: false config